# Synonymize [ocean] and [oceanography]

Tags: discussion, tags

I just saw that [weather](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather) and [meteorology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteorology) were synonymized now, shouldn't we synonymized, in a similar way, tags [ocean](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocean) and [oceanography](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oceanography)?
I don't really think there is a good reason to keep them separate.
There is currently 58 questions tagged with [ocean](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocean), 40 with [oceanography](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oceanography), including 23 that are tagged with both of them.

You can found the page to vote on the synonymy [here](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tags/oceanography/synonyms).

Answer (score 5):

Making [ocean](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocean) and [oceanography](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oceanography) synonyms is closer to making [meteorology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteorology) and [atmosphere](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere) synonyms rather that with [weather](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather).  I'll defer to others within the ocean domain, but I will point you at [this discussion](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186/should-atmosphere-be-a-synonym-of-meteorology) regarding [meteorology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteorology) and [atmosphere](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere).

Also note that you (the community) can create synonyms without our (moderator) intervention.  If you have 1,250 rep and at least 5 upvotes in the tag, you can suggest a synonym and then anyone with at least 5 upvotes in the tag can vote on the synonym.  When you get 4 votes up on the suggestion it becomes a synonym.  See: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

Comment: I did suggest a synonym a couple of months ago, but nobody reacted to it, hence this meta post. In the meta post on meteorology and atmosphere, one of the reason invoked for the separation is that not all questions about meteorology pertain to the atmosphere and not all questions about atmosphere pertain to meteorology, but it seems to me that we can't say the same about ocean/oceanography.

Comment: @plannapus Good point, which is one of the reasons I'm deferring on that point myself.  You might link to the tag synonym page in your post to draw attention to getting votes.  Your suggest is still active (until it gets either -2 or +4).  You suggested to make oceanography->ocean, I swapped that to ocean->oceanography but I can revert that if you really intended the first ordering.

Comment: No you're right i intended ocean->oceanography indeed.